# Large dataset of galaxies redshift, mass, and metallicity?

Tags: distances, mass, raw-data, metallicity

I'm curious if there is a standard dataset for redshift-mass or redshift-metallicity like there is for redshift-distance with Pantheon+SH0ES.

https://github.com/PantheonPlusSH0ES/DataRelease/tree/main/Pantheon%2B_Data/4_DISTANCES_AND_COVAR

There is NED, which has millions of redshifts, but mass and metallicity aren't part of its results.

http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/

It'd be nice to have 10's of thousands (if not more) data points available with one or both of those properties. Does such a project exist?

Comment: Mass continues to grow with radius for galaxies and  depends on assumed distance. Metallicity varies with radius and method used to deduce it.  Catalogs tend to stick to unambiguous observable, like flux within a certain subtended angular radius.   The best is probably Hyperleda.